# Differentiate between first download of the page and all subsequent downloads of the same page

Tags: javascript, nginx, http-headers, tornado

I have a static page (by static, I mean html, css and javascript are fixed on the page).

On the server side, I can tell (based on server-side session info) whether this is the first loading of the page or not by a particular user. Now, based on this detail, I want to signal the front end (e.g. by setting something in the response header, maybe?), so that a javascript function on the page can perform some action based on whether this is the first time the user has landed on this page.

The server that actually serves the page is Nginx, and the server that handles the logic, session, etc is Tornado. So presumably I need to do something in tornado, and then instruct nginx to deliver the static page.

Is this doable? If so, what is the most robust way of doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this with cookies: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
WIth cookies you would send a specific cookie w/ the response headers on the first view. Then each time the page loads, have your javascript check the specific cookie

Or use local storage: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
Similar to the cookie method, but on the first view have javascript store a key=value pair in local storage, and check against that each time the page loads. Something along these lines:

```
(function () {
    window.onload = function () {
        if (localStorage.getItem("SeenBefore")) {
            // Not first time viewed
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("SeenBefore", true);
            // First view
        }
    }
}())
```

Another option is, on the serverside, you could set a session variable the first time the page is viewed, then check agianst that each time a user sends a request for the page. This could also be achieved using cookies.

Comment: I thought about both methods above, but the main problem with both is that (because client-side javascript is involved), users can modify the cookie or local storage variable themselves, which may compromise the functionalities I want to perform. If the thing javascript is going to check for comes from server directly, then it is less likely that users can affect the behavior easily.

Comment: The problem with that is any behavior you wish to be handled on the client side can be manipulated via a user.